# Deleting contacts on iCloud does not remove them from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, contacts, contacts.app

I've used iCloud's website to clean up contacts that were imported and the changes work...except - if I delete a contact on the iCloud website it does not get deleted on the iPhone. How can I force the deleted contacts on iCloud to be removed from the iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the contacts that were not being deleted were linked to Google and Yahoo accounts. The data from them were imported to iCloud. I'm pretty sure iCloud *was* deleting the contacts from the iPhone that I deleted on the website/desktop. I went in to Settings, Accounts and disabled showing the contacts for Google and Yahoo and all the trashy contacts disappeared.